# Implementing Request/Reply Pattern with Spring and RabbitMQ with already existing queues

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

Let me start by describing the system.  There are 2 applications, let's call them **Client** and **Server**.  There are also 2 queues, request queue and reply queue.  The **Client** publishes to the request queue, and the server listens for that request to process it.  After the **Server** processes the message, it publishes it to the reply queue, which the **Client** is subscribed to.  The **Server** application always publishes the reply to the predefined reply queue, not a queue that the **Client** application determines.

I cannot make updates to the **Server** application.  I can only update the **Client** application.  The queues are created and managed by the **Server** application.

I am trying to implement request/reply pattern from **Client**, such that the reply from the **Server** is synchronously returned.  I am aware of the "sendAndReceive" approach with spring, and how it works with a temporary queue for reply purposes, and also with a fixed reply queue.

[Spring AMQP - 3.1.9 Request/Reply Messaging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#request-reply)

*Here are the questions I have:*

1. Can I utilize this approach with existing queues, which are managed and created by the **Server** application?  If yes, please elaborate.
2. If my **Client** application is a scaled app (multiple instances of it are running at the same time), then how do I also implement it in such a way, that the wrong instance (one in which the request did not originate) does not read the reply from the queue?
3. Am I able to use the "Default" exchange to my advantage here, in addition to a routing key?

Thanks for your time and your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes; simply use a [Reply Listener Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#reply-listener) wired into the `RabbitTemplate`.

IMPORTANT: the server must echo the `correlationId` message property set by the client, so that the reply can be correlated to the request in the client.

2. You can't. Unlike JMS, RabbitMQ has no notion of message selection; each consumer (in this case, reply container) needs its own queue. Otherwise, the instances will get random replies and it is possible (highly likely) that the reply will go to the wrong instance.

> ...it publishes it to the reply queue...

With RabbitMQ, publishers don't publish to queues, they publish to exchanges with a routing key. It is bad practice to tightly couple publishers to queues. If you can't change the **server** to publish the reply to an exchange, with a routing key that contains something from the request message (or use the `replyTo` property), you are out of luck.

3. Using the default exchange encourages the bad practice I mentioned in 2 (tightly coupling producers to queues). So, no, it doesn't help.

**EDIT**

If there's something in the reply that allows you to correlate it to a request; one possibility would be to add a delegating consumer on the server's reply queue. Receive the reply, perform the correlation, route the reply to the proper `replyTo`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and feedback, appreciate it.I have seen your [examples](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/8900257) and plan on using them within the **Client** application.  In a future development iteration, we look to improve the **Server** application and the queue management, and migrate to exchanges.

Comment: Would you consider it a sound approach if each scaled **Client** instance created its own unique reply queue and then bound it to the reply exchange that the **Server** application publishes to?  The binding would use a routing key that is unique to that instance application such as a UUID.  Would it be best to use a direct exchange for the reply exchange?

Comment: Yes, a direct exchange would be the right type in that case. The cleanest approach, though would be to have the server just send to the `replyTo` property. In Spring AMQP, on the server side, the `MessageListenerAdapter` (and `@RabbitListener`) consider a `replyTo` with format `foo/bar` meaning publish to `foo` with a routing key `bar`. That way, the server doesn't even have to know which exchange he's replying to.